# Is return *array; valid?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, pointers

Is it valid to return a pointer to an array in C++ like this?

```
int* function(int n){
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<=n ; i++){
       int array[i] = i;
   }
  return *array;
}
```

What would be the correct way?

Comment: correction int* function()...

Comment: You can use [edit] for corrections, rather than commenting.

Comment: Can you confirm that your example is meant to have `array` defined in a scope where it is not accessible by the return statement?

Comment: Sometimes it's valid, other times it's not. Your question as it stands is to vague and broad to be accurately answered.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.. The point of the question was developing a function that takes a 'n' as parameter and sets all the positions until 'n' in the array with its index value, for ex: array[0] = 0, array[1] = 1.. etc and to return a pointer to the array

Comment: Please choose a better example. Your code will not compile at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Never in C++ AFAICT, since it would be initializing an array with an `int`, and I've never come across a language extension for that.

Comment: @chris Oh right, that as well.

Comment: What did I just read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, because it is the way you should return it. No, because you should (and have to) use `new[]` operator (or `malloc` function). So basically you should write:

```
int* function(int n){
 int i = 0;
 int *array = new int[n]; // or c-style malloc(n*sizeof(int))
 for(i = 0; i<=n ; i++){
  array[i] = i;
 }
 return array;
}
```

Why? Because if you create an array with `int array[i]` it will 'disappear' when function end (it's all about variable range).

Comment: No, sorry, this is bad advice. You should **not** use either `malloc` or `new` here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you tell more why?

Comment: @elwin013 Briefly, http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1

Comment: @KonradRudolph I disagree, pointers are not bad, but must be used with caution, if you want to be on safe side you can use smart pointers, but not using pointers at all is limiting. Sometimes you want arrays, even dynamic ones, especially when you want serialize something and vectors only recently got data method. Also it's good for you to know how to use pointers in case you will need to write something in C (you never know...).

Comment: @Piotr *Pointers* aren’t bad, but *this particular use* of pointers is always bad, no exception. And what do you mean with “vectors only recently got data method”? And what has serialisation got to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not even close to being compilable. If you meant something like:

```
int *foo()
{
     int x[5] = { 0 };
     return x;
}
```

then this code is not correct, because the array `x` ceases to exist when `foo()` returns, so the pointer will no longer be pointing to valid storage.

The options are:

- Have the caller allocate space and the function writes into that space
- Return a container that holds an array, such as `std::vector` in C++
- Return a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array in C. The caller must remember to `free` it when done.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it valid to return a pointer to an array in C++ like this?

No. Your example will not compile at all:

```
error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
```

http://ideone.com/h17cH1

It is OK to return a pointer to an array, if this array is not automatic variable, so it still exists after function returns. In example:

```
int* function(int n){
   int * array = new int[i]();
   return array;
}
```

Not beautiful though as it is not obvious who should delete this array and when.